# Determining elevation of polylines using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem, elevation

I am attempting to determine the elevation of about 100k different polylines. I have an associated DEM for my state that is in the same coordinate system.

What tool(s) could I use to determine the mean elevation of each polyline and add this information to the attribute table?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, and thank you for taking the tour. Please [Edit] your Question to conform to the One question per Question policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to find the solution, it was to run the 3D Analyst tool, Add Surface Information. Someone had a very similar question about ten years back and posted it to the ESRI blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3D Analyst extension you could use the [Interpolate shape](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/interpolate-shape.htm) tool to transfer your DEM to the vertices of the polylines. Then use the [Add geometry Attributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) to extract first/last Z values and finally compute the mean with a field calculate?